# Web Content Editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-content

Is there any web content editor (like FCKEditor or WMD editor) that allows page layouts (images, tables etc.) like MS Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both FCK and TinyMCE allow for tables and other layout elements (overall FCK having the better implementation of added elements), and both will allow images that you have a url for.

There is a plug-in for Tiny that allows image uploading, but it is heavy and I think proprietary.

Neither of the above is an inline editor, if that's what you want.  Probably the best in that direction currently is TiddlyWiki.

I have been working on my own Mootools based implementation that will allow any webpage to be edited, and has image uploading et al built in.  It is currently in Beta, but I can send you a link if that's your goal.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what exactly you ask for regarding page layouts, but telerik has a very feature rich html editor. It's a commercial product though.

Take a look at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: Our company tried to use Telerik's editor, and we found it was not very good, and it wasn't good for editting in blocks or partials.

Answer (score 2):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) is the closest candidate to MSWord... Obviously, being a web interface, it cannot be EXACTLY like Word, but it has a number of word's features.